# CSS display:none and visibility:hidden

Tags: css, hide, hidden

I have a div that I use to display alerts when needed.

If I want to close it after a while can I use display:none or should I use display:none as well as visibility:hidden?

So one or both.

Thank you.

Comment: display: none only will work just fine

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depends. If you need the space to be left blank, that is, the space won't be taken up by other elements below or around it, you'll need `visibility: hidden`. Otherwise, use `display: none`, which will allow other elements to move into the element's place.

There's no reason to use both.

Answer (score 6):

Visibility:hidden hides the element but it still takes up space in the layout. Display:none removes it completely.

In your case, I would use Display:none

Comment: there is no display:hidden, there is visibility:hidden :)

Comment: That's what I get for typing before coffee! Thanks for the catch, I updated my post. :)

Answer (score 6):

If your hidden content needs to be accessible—to those with screen readers, for example—then you should not use `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`, as both can potentially hide content from screen readers.  Instead, you should use a more accessible approach, such as moving the content off screen with a negative margin.  See the following links for more information:

[456 Berea Street: Hiding with CSS: Problems and solutions](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200905/hiding_with_css_problems_and_solutions/)
[WebAIM Blog: Hiding content for screen readers](http://webaim.org/blog/hiding-content-for-screen-readers/)

Comment: Just curious, but why exactly would you want to hide content but still have it be accessible to screen readers? If it's hidden, it's because I don't currently want it shown.

Comment: @MrN00b You might be hiding content for aesthetic reasons, such as collapsable sections that the user can hide or reveal.