# Difference between "visibility:collapse" and "display:none"

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between `visibility:collapse` and `display:none`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42252682/3597276

Answer (score 121):

**Short version:**

The former is used to completely hide table elements. The latter is used to completely hide everything else.

**Long version**:

`visibility: collapse` hides an element entirely (so that it doesn't occupy any space in the layout), but only when [the element is a table element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#visibility).

If used on elements other than table elements, `visibility: collapse` will act like `visibility: hidden`. This makes an element invisible, *but it will still occupy space in the layout.*

`display: none` hides an element *entirely*, so it doesn't occupy any space in the layout, but it shouldn't be used on table elements.

[W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#visibility)

Comment: This is useful, but a citation or explanation for the claim that `display: none` shouldn't be used on table elements would be a nice addition.

Comment: @MarkAmery A good reason to not use `display: none;` is because it breaks tables using `colspan` and `rowspan`.

Comment: @MarkAmery As Dai mentioned, if you use `display: none;` on a table cell then the table is displayed as if that cell weren't there at all: it will shift the other cells left to occupy that space instead.

Comment: @Brandon and that's what I want (to hide an entire col)

Answer (score 44):

`visibility: collapse` behaves exactly like `visibility: hidden` in most formatting contexts: the space required by the element is 'reserved' in the layout, but the element itself is not rendered, leaving a blank space where it would have been.

There are three exceptions that I know of: table-rows, table-columns and flex items, in which `visibility: collapse` behaves like `display: none`, but with one major difference: the 'strut'. You can think of the strut as a zero-sized placeholder, that doesn't claim any space of its own in the layout process, but is nevertheless still part of the formatting structure and participates in some size computations.

A collapsed table-row, for example, will not occupy any vertical space in the table, but the table columns will still be dimensioned 'as-if' the collapsed row and its contents were actually visible. This is to prevent columns from 'wobbling' as rows are toggled in and out. Likewise, a collapsed flex item doesn't occupy any space along the main axis, but still contributes to the flex line cross-size.

'Do not use `display: none` with tables' is a valuable rule of thumb, but it doesn't tell the whole story.

- Use `display: none` if you don't want your hidden elements to participate in any way in the table (or flex line) layout process.
- Use `visibility: collapse` if you want to dynamically show and hide elements  without destabilizing the table (or flex line) layout.

Here is a code snippet demonstrating the difference between `display: none` and `visibility: collapse` for a table row:

```css
.show-right-border {
  border-right: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<h3>visibility: collapse</h3>
<table class="show-right-border">
  <tr>
    <td>Short text.</td>
    <td style="visibility: collapse;">Loooooooooong text.</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h3>display: none</h3>
<table class="show-right-border">
  <tr>
    <td>Short text.</td>
    <td style="display: none;">Loooooooooong text.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Only one telling the full story. @Mathieu Renda you should edit the main answer adding all this knowledge.

Comment: `visibility:collapse` doesn't work for tables in Safari.  I found `display:none` to work fine on table rows (including in Safari) although the comments above about column width are correct

Answer (score 20):

`visibility:collapse` should only be used on tables. On other elements it will act as a `visibility:hidden`.

`visibility:hidden` hide the element but still take the space of the element whereas `display:none` won't even keep the space.

---

**Resources :**

- [w3schools.com - visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_visibility.asp)
- [w3schools.com - display](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp)

**On the same topic :**

- [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)
- [CSS Properties: Display vs. Visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility)
- [CSS display:none and visibility:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574623/css-displaynone-and-visibilityhidden)
- [Does opacity:0 have exactly the same effect as visibility:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden)

Answer (score 5):

`visibility:collapse` has a `display:none` behavior only for table elements. On other elements, it should render as `hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also apply `visibility: collapse` on an element under a flexbox container (a flex item). It will act as you're applying it on an element with `display: table-row` or `display: table-column`